# EC2+Mongo or Something+SimpleDB

Tags: amazon-ec2, mongodb, simpledb

I'm new to the db and cloud world.

So I'm writing an app that needs to query a very simple data (open/closed status of some location).

I thought of two options:

1) An ec2 micro instance running LAMP + MongoDB, and I wrote a php page that will query the db, format it and returns it.

2) i also looked at Amazon SimpleDB, the idea is by using it I don't need to run an ec2 instance 24/7, which can save me money. **But where should I put the php page that query the SimpleDB then?** It doesn't make sense to put it in an ec2 instance as the idea is to save money by not running it 24/7. I also learnt that I shouldn't connect to the database from my app cause that will expose my username/password of the database.

Answer (score 2):

The micro instances are a real pain whenever you want to do something with them. They run out of cpu and become unreachable for a couple of minutes whenever you have a high load.

SimpleDB sounds more like a better choice for you if you don't want to run your own database. If you only have a simple PHP page with queries for a database, you could put it on a number of cheap PHP web hosting sites.

As a side note: if you are going to install MongoDB on a micro instance, make sure you run it on a 64-bit system. I had a lot of strange errors coming from MongoDB (high CPU usage when the process should be idle) when using it on a 32-bit micro instance.